# Docker stack deploy is not deploying because its the same image tag

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I try to deploy in docker swarm one stack with an image that has the same tag/version than the deployed one, docker don't deploy or update with the new image (although is different, has the same version/tag, I know that is not correct and I'm working on have inmutable images with different tags always, but, meanwhile I have to continue).

Is there anyway to force to deploy it even the image has the same tag?  I need it without downtime, so, use docker delete stack XXX it's not usefull for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker swarm (stack deploy and service create/update) pulls the image metadata and updates the service tasks image ref with the sha256 hash. This means that swarm will redeploy even in cases where a common tag like :latest has been changed.

You need to suppress this by passing a value other than the default of `always` to `docker stack deploy --resolve-image <always|changed|never> ...` if you don't want this behaviour. In cases where you do want the default behaviour, leave it out or, if you must, pass `always`.